# Is Keyed Node meant to be used with Lazy?

Tags: elm

I am reading about optimization in the Elm Guide. It talks about [keyed nodes](https://guide.elm-lang.org/optimization/keyed.html), using US Presidents as an example:

```
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Keyed as Keyed
import Html.Lazy exposing (lazy)

viewPresidents : List President -> Html msg
viewPresidents presidents =
  Keyed.node "ul" [] (List.map viewKeyedPresident presidents)

viewKeyedPresident : President -> (String, Html msg)
viewKeyedPresident president =
  ( president.name, lazy viewPresident president )

viewPresident : President -> Html msg
viewPresident president =
  li [] [ ... ]
```

Then give this as an explanation:

> Now the Virtual DOM implementation can recognize when the list is resorted. It first matches all the presidents up by key. Then it diffs those. We used lazy for each entry, so we can skip all that work. Nice! It then figures out how to shuffle the DOM nodes to show things in the order you want. So the keyed version does a lot less work in the end.

My confusion is this: **If I don't use `lazy` inside the keyed nodes**, the Virtual DOM still has to diff every entry of the list, even if it can match some keys. It seems keyed nodes' usefulness really depends on the `lazy` inside. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: My understanding is that they work on different levels. `lazy` uses memoization to skip parts of the computation for the virtual DOM tree. Keyed nodes reduces the number of DOM operations by matching DOM nodes with their corresponding nodes in the virtual DOM tree.

Comment: That's my understanding too. But it seems to me that keyed nodes' effectiveness would be greatly reduced if `lazy` is not used at the same time. I just want to confirm the suspicion.

Comment: Whether you use `lazy` or not should produce the exact same virtual DOM tree. Using `lazy` will just return a previously computed virtual DOM fragment instead of re-computing it. I don't see how they'd effect each other at all.

Comment: OK. If I don't use `lazy`, each entry in a list will be re-computed regardless of the key match. Isn't it?

Comment: Yes, that's my understanding. It's just memoization, meaning that the result is cached based on its inputs, and only its inputs.

Comment: So, if `lazy` is not used, keyed nodes don't really help, because each entry in a list is re-computed anyway. That's what _it seems to me_. I would like to confirm it.

Comment: Each _Virtual DOM_ fragment is re-computed, yes, but then the virtual DOM is diffed against the DOM, and where they don't match the DOM is changed so that they do. Keyed nodes just help reduce the number of DOM operations needed by identifying which DOM and Virtual DOM nodes correspond to each other.

Comment: Also, manipulating the DOM tends to be much more expensive than re-computing the virtual DOM fragments, so it's often sufficient to just use keyed nodes.

Comment: Now, you really got me confused. According to the Elm Guide's [Lazy page](https://guide.elm-lang.org/optimization/lazy.html), the Virtual DOM is diffed against the previous Virtual DOM. Only then does it know how to modify the real DOM.

Comment: It's basically the same thing. Elm assumes that the previous virtual DOM matches the current DOM, which is usually true (but not always, if you're using an extension which manipulates the DOM, for example).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let's consider an example:

- **name**: Apple, **price**: $3.2, **pic**:
- **name**: Banana, **price**: $2, **pic**:
- **name**: Orange, **price**: $2.8, **pic**:

Now let's imagine that the user sorts by price:

- **name**: Banana, **price**: $2, **pic**:
- **name**: Orange, **price**: $2.8, **pic**:
- **name**: Apple, **price**: $3.2, **pic**:

without keyed nodes, the diffing is going to look like this:

- **name**: <del>Apple</del>*Banana*, **price**: $<del>3.2</del>2, **pic**:
- **name**: <del>Banana</del>*Orange*, **price**: $<del>2</del>*2.8*, **pic**:
- **name**: <del>Orange</del>*Apple*, **price**: $<del>2.8</del>*3.2*, **pic**:

which is going to issue in this example 9 `replaceElement` operations with 9 `createTextElement` operations (for example, the exact semantics might work slighly differently, but I think the point stands).

The keyed version will understand that the order changed and will issue a single `removeChild` and `appendChild` for the apple node.

Hence all the performance savings are on the DOM side. Now this is not just for performance, if those lists had input elements, keeping them keyed if you had your cursor in the Apple input, it would stay in the apple input, but if they weren't keyed, it would now be in the banana input.

You are correct that without lazy the diffing still happens, but the diffing is generally the cheap part, the more expensive part is actually patching the DOM, which is what keyed helps prevent.

Comment: "You are correct that without lazy the diffing still happens" I don't think `lazy` has anything to do with diffing. It memoizes parts of the virtual DOM, but the whole virtual DOM still needs to be diffed regardless.